# Execute assembly generated at Runtime from Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, interpreter, roslyn, emit

I'm currently trying to generate and execute some C# code directly from a Xamarin.iOS code editor application I'm working on. I use [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) for all the compilation steps, but unfortunately, Mono doesn't allow you to load Assemblies at Runtime on iOS.

So, this code would typically throw a `Attempting to JIT compile method while running with --aot-only`exception.

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"public Foo
{
    public void Bar() { Console.WriteLine(""""foo"""");
}");

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
        "Generated." + Guid.NewGuid(),
        syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
        references: references,
        options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var result = compilation.Emit(ms);          
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(ms); // <- Thrown here
}
```

I know that [Frank A. Krueger](https://mobile.twitter.com/praeclarum) did a custom interpreter for IL for his awesome [Continuous](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/continuous-.net-c-and-f-ide/id1095213378?mt=8) application.

I imagine having a similar approach but directly from the `SemanticModel` and `SyntaxTrees` outputted by Roslyn because I only want to support C#.

Regarding the pretty huge codebase of Roslyn, are there some bits I can pickup to base my interpreter on ?

Another question, without the possibility to generate Types dynamically, how could I represent those dynamic declared Types at Runtime ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the Continuous github https://github.com/praeclarum/Continuous project from great Frank?

Answer (score 0):

The ecosystem on iOS does not allow dynamically generated code. It's also part of legal restrictions for iOS platform.